# how to export images from DB to SD Card

Tags: android, export, android-sdcard

this method help me to show images from db to imgview.
so how to save it on SD Card ?

```
private Bitmap setImage(String base64String) {
    Bitmap bmp = null;
    try {
        if (base64String == null || base64String.equals("")) {


        } else {

            byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(base64String, Base64.DEFAULT);

            bmp =  BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bmp;
}
```

Eclipse
Android 2.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

get the bitmap return from the your method and u can store that bitmap into sdcard.

in android we can save the bitmap in the fellowing way.

Then you must get to directory (a File object) from SD Card such as:

```
File deviceSdcardDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

Next, create your specific file for image storage:

```
File image = new File(deviceSdcardDirectory, "file_name.png");
```

After that, you just have to write the Bitmap :

```
// Encode the file as a PNG image.
FileOutputStream outStream;
try {

    outStream = new FileOutputStream(image);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream); 
    /* 100 to keep full quality of the image */

    outStream.flush();
    outStream.close();

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Don't forget to add the following permission in your Manifest File:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```